# Как создать проект на React Native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

После команды create-react-app MyApp командная строка пишет, что  'command not found', хотя должен запуститься процесс создания приложения на React.

Почему так происходит?

Node установлен,
package.json есть,
node_modules есть.

Дерево проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установи глобально `create-react-app`:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Если `macOS` или `Linux` добавь `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

После установки создай проект:

```
create-react-app MyApp
```

И запусти:

```
cd MyApp
npm install
npm start
```

Comment: Сделал переустановку Node. Использовал brew-команды. Вышло так, что было установлено две версии Node.

Comment: @DmitryNikitin что в итоге? получилось создать проект, после всех изменений?

Comment: Пишу команду npm start. В итоге, Starting packager... и все зависает. Как же понять, что сервер стартанул? Буду делать restart.

Comment: @DmitryNikitin он должен автоматически открыть сайт, пакеты установили все? `npm install` запусти перед старом проекта

Comment: You must install peer dependencies yourself. Это в качестве warning появилось после npm install.

Comment: @DmitryNikitin `npm install --peer` попробуй

Comment: да, он говорит, что "пиры" надо установить самому. делается это в package.json . "peerDependencies": {
    "AwesomeProject": "0.1.0"
  }, пробовал - пока не помогает. ищу пример синтаксиса